# Install Flmngr file manager server side on PHP Codiginter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

How we can configigure **Flmngr **file manager server side using Codiginter4.

require base_url().'ThirdParty/autoload.php';
use EdSDK\FlmngrServer\FlmngrServer;

class FilemanagerController extends BaseController
{
public $session;

```
/**
 * constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->session = session();
}

public function index(){
    FlmngrServer::flmngrRequest(
        array(
            'dirFiles' => '/uploads',
            'dirTmp'   => 'tmp',
            'dirCache' => 'cache'
        )
    );
}
```

}

Comment: What isn't working for you? What have you tried so far? Do you get any errors?